# Angular 9 - Placeholder localization

Tags: angular, angular-material, internationalization

Hi I have a solution where it uses Angular material also. The code of the textarea is as below. I am trying to localize the placeholder text with no luck.

```
        <mat-form-field>
          <textarea id="external-summary" rows="5" matInput #external placeholder="External"               
            i18n-placeholder="@@state-external" data-fieldId=10003 data-fieldName="External"
            cdkTextareaAutosize cdkAutosizeMinRows="5" cdkAutosizeMaxRows="100%" appCapitalizeFirstLetter class="hide-scrollbar" 
            formControlName="external" (change)="update(external.value,CategoryTypes.External)">
          </textarea>
        </mat-form-field>
```

And in the language.xlf file I have added the entry:

```
        <trans-unit id="state-external" datatype="html">
            <source>External</source>
            <target state="final">Utvendige</target>
            <context-group purpose="location">
                <context context-type="sourcefile">app/report/summary-state/external-summary.component.html</context>
                <context context-type="linenumber">29</context>
            </context-group>
        </trans-unit>
```

But still the placeholder in the Text area displays as "External" instead of displaying the intended localized value which is "Utvendige"

What can be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use i18n-attributename. So you don't need to use Angular Material here. For example:

```
<input type="number" placeholder="From" i18n-placeholder="From placeholder"/>
```

That would need an entry like this:

```
<trans-unit id="generatedId" datatype="html">
  <source>From</source>
  <target state="translated">Van</target>
  <note priority="1" from="description">From placeholder</note>
</trans-unit>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. Have a quick clarification. How does the i18n-placeholder attribute locate the trans-unit here ? I thought that you need to reference the trans-unit by  id. But here you have mentioned the content in the "note".